# A Few Gmail Schema Questions

Tags: gmail, schema.org

1) After a user rates an item is there a store of past rates? Can they be filtered/displayed by sender, item/vendor rated or some other aspect within the schema?

2) Will there be integration for mailers such as Constant Contact for user response metrics?

3) Can items like rate be re-purposed for things, like say I wanted use a server component to insert a standard disposition for the email. Users would have their Gmail Inbox, but would also find copies of all this mail in their SugarCRM_Inbox, the server has retrieved and inserted a disposition schema; the user can choose 
- personal
- contact
- company
- project etc...(sugarCRM modules/objects)

When the user makes a choice, a round trip to the server retrieves a list for the selected object and/or the admin can choose that when "contact" is chosen, the email is automatically filed in the contact's history in the SugarCRM database as Un-Read, similarly with personal where the email can be removed from the SugarCRM_Inbox and only reside in the Gmail Inbox; so with the list of items retrieved the user selects which contact to bind to, still un-read later filing will be automatic and having been disposed with 3-clicks (select email, object type, item in the list); this can occur from any device in Gmail.

3) Alternate use same functionality; rate my restaurant, What entree did you have? (drop down list is returned) etc for the entire meal, multiple choices, perhaps a G+ integration?

4) Connectors like zapier.com to perform advanced functions

Answer (score 1):

1) Reviews are sent to the third-party which can store/filter/display them

2) Mailers such as Constant Contact can check http://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas to learn how to add schema to their emails and templates

3) what you describe seems like a complex workflow that I'm not sure should live inside Gmail.  That is not part of the first release, we'll consider it (as well as any other proposal) for future releases

4) not currently planned, but in general complex multi-step actions shouldn't be performed in a small UI inside Gmail

5) we really hope for a lot of third-parties to support this open technology, by either using it directly or writing libraries and connectors for it